# Replicating HTTP requests with PHP & cURL

Tags: php, cookies, curl, http-headers, httprequest

I am trying to request a password protected page from something called "CM/ECF" (Pacer) to view court dockets and such with PHP/cURL.

I am using a FireFox extension called Tamper Data which allows me to see headers and POST data, then trying to replicate that request PHP using cURL.

It's not working for some reason, I keep getting a request to log in. I can log in just fine, save the cookie to the cookie jar and get the the "Main" page, but when I do a second curl call (sending the same cookie) to the search page the host redirects me to a login page.

Two part question:
Part 1 - When I use TaperData to view the cookies that are sent when I request the page, TamperData shows me this:

```
PacerUser="xxxxxxxxxxx                               xxxxxxx"; 
PacerSession="xxxxxSW8+F/BCzRxxxxxxhYtWpfO4ZR8WTEYbnaeeoVixAp5YnKMWxxxxxx0U8MoEPt2FOxxxxxxx/5B9ujb"; 
PacerPref="receipt=Y"; 
PacerClientCode=""; 
__utma=20643455934534311.139983455.139934505.13998383455.1; 
__utmb=206345345.10.13453405; 
__utmc=2053453433351; 
__utmz=20653453351.1399345345.1.utmcsr=pacer.gov|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/cmecf/developer/
```

But the cookie file generated by libcurl doesn't include any of the lines that begin with an underscore. What are those?

Here's the request my browser makes, copied from TamperData:

```
Host=ecf.almb.uscourts.gov
User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0
Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language=en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate
DNT=1
Cookie=PacerUser="wmasdfasdf                                ZFBgasdfasdfsdff PacerSession="7rkPasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfsdadfnaeeoVixAp5YnKMW9lokKeq4ss4m0U8MoEPt2FOj2P/51RLh/5B9ujb"; PacerPref="receipt=Y"; PacerClientCode=""; __utma=203145253483351.15234521.13998234523405.139234505.139982345305.1; __utmc=2034533351; __utmz=206453453351.14538105.1.1.utmcsr=pacer.gov|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/cmecf/developer/
Connection=keep-alive
Cache-Control=max-age=0
```

Here's my PHP

```
$Headers = array(
    "Host: ".$this->CaseFiled_endpoints[$district],
    "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
    "Connection: keep-alive"
);        


$url = "https://".$this->CaseFiled_endpoints[$district]."/cgi-bin/CaseFiled-Rpt.pl";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $Headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($this->cookiefile));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath($this->cookiefile));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$answer2 = curl_exec($ch);

return curl_getinfo($ch);
```

Is there anything blatantly wrong with my code? Are there any other tools that might make this easier? A browser plugin that spits out curl code?

Comment: You can safely ignore the `*utm*` cookies. They are from google analytics and adsense. I'd suggest comparing the full http transactions for regular browsing with your browser, and for your script. A tool such as Wireshark, although very advanced, will give you the full network stream for your to compare.

Comment: remove curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true); - as per my answer update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the magic soup you are missing, a $cookie file in curl_setopt.

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
```

then you would fist curl post to the login form, save the cookie file, and then check for the filetime on the cookie ( to see if its out of date ) and create new cookie or send the $cookie file in your subsequent requests.

note i dont have this line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
```

also note http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION.html

> Pass a long set to 1 to mark this as a new cookie "session". It will
>   force libcurl to ignore all cookies it is about to load that are
>   "session cookies" from the previous session. By default, libcurl
>   always stores and loads all cookies, independent if they are session
>   cookies or not. Session cookies are cookies without expiry date and
>   they are meant to be alive and existing for this "session" only.

I think you are telling it to start a new session every time.

p.s. - I use pacer as well.

```
public function Login(){
        $cookie_file = __DIR__."/cookie.txt";
        $cookie_file = str_replace("\\", "/", $cookie_file);
        $this->_cookie_file = $cookie_file;
        $new_file = false;
        if(!is_file($cookie_file)){
            $h = fopen($cookie_file, "w");
            fclose($h);
            $file_time = time();
            $new_file = true;
        }else{
            $file_time = filemtime($cookie_file);
        }

        //login
        if($file_time < (time() - 1800) || $new_file){
            $url = "https://pacer.login.uscourts.gov/cgi-bin/check-pacer-passwd.pl";
            $post = array(
                    "loginid"=>"loginID",
                    "passwd"=>"password",
                    "client"=> "client",
                    "faction"=>"Login",
                    "appurl"=>"https://pcl.uscourts.gov/search"
            );


            $res = $this->_cUrl->cPost($url, $post, $cookie_file);
            $this->Log("LOGGING IN AT ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
            sleep(2);
            $this->Log("SLEEPING 2 ..",E_USER_DEPRECATED);
        }

    }
```

from my curl library class.

```
public function cPost($url, $post, $cookie_file="cookie.txt"){
        if(is_array($post)){
            $post_string = $this->encodePost($post);
        }else{
            $post_string = $post;
        }

        $cookie = str_replace("\\", "/", $cookie_file);
        $fc = fopen($cookie, "r");
        fclose($fc);
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $this->_error_handle); 
        fwrite($this->_error_handle,"Starting debug file ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n");

        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1"); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true); // enable tracking
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
        $result = curl_exec ($ch); 
        if ( curl_errno($ch) ) {
            $response = 'ERROR -> ' . curl_errno($ch) . ': ' . curl_error($ch);
            throw new CurlException($response);
        } else {
            $returnCode = (int)curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            switch($returnCode){
                case 404:
                    $response = 'ERROR -> 404 Not Found';
                    throw new CurlException($response, CurlException::ER_RETURN_CODE);
                break;
                default:

                break;
            }
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
```

to access there search form.

```
$url = "https://pcl.uscourts.gov/dquery";
        $post = array(
            "case_no"=>$case_no,
            "mdl_id"=>"",
            "stitle"=>"",
            "nos"=> array(
                    "370",
                    "371",
                    "440",
                    "470",
                    "480",
                    "890"
                ),
            "date_filed_start"=>$date_filed_start,
            "date_filed_end"=>$date_filed_end,
            "date_term_start"=>"",
            "date_term_end"=>"",
            "date_dismiss_start"=>"",
            "date_dismiss_end"=>"",
            "date_discharge_start"=>"",
            "date_discharge_end"=>"",
            "party"=>$party,
            "ssn4"=>"",
            "ssn"=>"",
            "court_type"=>"cv",
            "default_form"=>"cvb"
        );

        print_r($post);

        $html = $this->_cUrl->cPost($url, $post, $this->_cookie_file);
```

I have this code in production environment for over a year now - here are the keys to the kingdom lol.

Comment: Don't ask me about westlaw your on your own if you want help them.

Answer (score 4):

In Chromes network tab you can find the "Copy as cURL" functionality. It will the command line to the clipboard that will replicate that request with cURL. From there on it should be trivial to convert it into PHP code.

[image]

Comment: How to convert it to php curl ?