# Sending HTTP GET request to PACER to import court documents in R

Tags: r, http

Can anyone help me with sending HTTP GET request to PACER Case Locator (PCL)? I'm using R. The response code is 404: Not found. When I type the URL in the browser, it returns the same thing: Not Found. According to PACER, there is nothing wrong with PACER API. Other examples I tried in the httr package tutorials returns the response code 200. What am I doing wrong? I also tried with user name and password with the authenticate argument in the GET request, but didn't work. Thank you.

```
library(httr)
get_result <- GET("http://pcl.uscourts.gov/dquery")
get_result
## Response [https://pcl.uscourts.gov/dquery]
##   Date: 2018-02-07 13:34
##   Status: 404
##   Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
##   Size: 204 B
## <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
## <html><head>
## <title>404 Not Found</title>
## </head><body>
## <h1>Not Found</h1>
## <p>The requested URL /dquery was not found on this server.</p>
## </body></html>
```

Comment: At least two issues are apparent: first, that seems to be the [legacy API URL](https://www.pacer.gov/pclnew/) (scroll down to see the URL you need to use for legacy access). Second,  the `PACER-API-Documentation.pdf` you may be using as a reference states you need to pass in some auth data (the site charges for API calls just like it does for manual search results). This SO answer shows the need to obtain cookies from an auth event to pass to the API https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597732/replicating-http-requests-with-php-curl. To help further would require folks spending $.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about R or general coding but more asking for a tutorial on using an API or debugging an API which is out of scope for SO.

Comment: Thank you, hrbrmstr. The code worked after I changed the url to the legacy API URL as you pointed out. Hope you have a wonderful day!